# Use of writing function in specified manner in javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been writing functions like

```
var functionname = function(param)
{
}
```

rather then

```
functionname(param)
{
}
```

does it provide any advantage of the format or any garbage collection happens when i write like the first syntax?

Comment: in the first one, you are assigning an anonymous function to a variable. in the second you are declaring a named function. they can both be called similarly, so it shouldn't matter

Comment: It's strange to hear such basic questions from a hacker :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() { "use strict"; f(); function f() { console.log(1); }; })();
```

> > 1

```
(function() { "use strict"; f(); var f = function() { console.log(1); }; })();
```

> > Object expected

Function expressions *var name = function() { ... }* are not hoisted, while function decarations *function name() {...}* are.

Comment: `var name=...` also hoisted, but before assigning it _undefined_

Comment: also for second case: _Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function(…)_. this error in last chrome

Comment: @Grundy - Yes, that's exactly why i used the phrase "function expression" and not "function variable" or "variable". This is also why the output is "Object expected" and not "'name' is undefined"; though "Object expected" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: but not clear for me, what you mean _Object expected_, when error is _f not a function_

Comment: @Grundy - the more ambiguous "Object expected" error is reported by IE11. I suspect one browser is following the spec and the other isn't (or the specification is ill defined for tis error).

Comment: hm, you right, Edge also get _"Object expected"_. I not sure in what place of specification we can see what error should be :-)

Comment: interesting: type exception same: `TypeError` but different message :-)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, u should understand the scope matter for this function.

when u write:

var a = function(){} --> the function is anonymous outside the var a- scope.

it means, that out of this district, the function will not be able to be accessed. another thing is memory usage- here u create a function which takes memory, and a pointer outside the function pointing on it as a soft link.

when u write function a(){} ---> there is a public pointer named a for this function as a hard link.

so, if you want to create a private function- go for it.

i know that it's common to create functions using: function funcName(){);

Comment: methinks your explanation a bit wrong: one differense in first case _a_ before assigning is _undefined_ in second - _a_ function in all places current scope